# java.lang.IllegalStateException because of onResponse code in okhttp async HTTP POST request

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, leanback

I have written a code here:

```
public class Wizard1 extends GuidedStepFragment implements Callback {

    private boolean sendPhoneNumber(String userPhoneNumber) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("request_magic_code", Urls.REQUEST_MAGIC_CODE)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(Urls.HOST + Urls.SEND_PHONE_NUMBER)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(this);
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
        ResponseBody myResponse = response.body();
        Log.d("SS", response.body().string());

    Log.d("SS", response.body().string());

        if (myResponse != null) {
            success = true;
            }

}
```

When I run this, amazingly I get java.lang.IllegalStateException. More amazingly, **IF I REMOVE SECOND Log.d LINE, THE EXCEPTION WILL NOT OCCUR!**

What are happening? Why adding a dummy line in onResponse causes this error?

here is the full log of error:

> 10-24 05:16:38.307 6639-6659/com.example.android.persistence
>   W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
>           at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:398)
>           at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:392)
>           at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:431)
>           at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174) 10-24 05:16:38.308 6639-6659/com.example.android.persistence W/System.err:
>   at
>   android.support.v17.leanback.supportleanbackshowcase.app.wizard.WizardGetPhoneNumber.onResponse(WizardGetPhoneNumber.java:244)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
>           at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using `response.body().string()` twice

From the OkHttp 3 [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html):
**The response body can be consumed only once.**

You can create local variable and use it

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
    ResponseBody body = response.body();
    if(body != null) {
        try {
            //Use it anytime you want
            String responseString = body.string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can copy ResponseBody

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
    ResponseBody body = response.body();
    //Warning: this method loads the requested bytes into memory. Most
    // applications should set a modest limit on {@code byteCount}, such as 1 MiB.
    int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    ResponseBody copy = response.peekBody(bufferSize);
}
```

But be careful to use `bufferSize` correctly, to prevent [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

P.s. you don't need to log string to Logcat. There are few more efficient ways to debug OkHttp client such as

- https://github.com/itkacher/OkHttpProfiler - plugin for Android studio to profile OkHttp request
- https://www.charlesproxy.com/ - Proxy application for http (setup [manual](https://medium.com/@ievgeniitkachenko/different-ways-to-debug-https-requests-in-an-android-emulator-cbf4e0c8ce17))
- http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ - debug bridge for Android applications

Comment: Yes thanks, I was getting this due to 2 API calls having same response handling callback

Answer (score 3):

Body from `Retrofit` response can be accessed just one time, is cleared after is readed, in your case logged to console second time.

From documentation:

> A one-shot stream from the origin server to the client application with the raw bytes of the response body.

More details on [official documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html).

You should keep using the saved one, the `myResponse` variable.